# iExpress incompatibility with Windows 7, 32 bit?

Tags: windows, windows-7, iexpress

When I create an .exe with iExpress (in Windows 8) and try to run it on Win7, 32 bit, I get an error dialog that says:  "The version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running.  Check your computer's system information to see whether you need an x86 (32 bit) or x64 (64 bit) version of the program."

Is an iExpress .exe incompatible with Win 7 32 bit??

Comment: Try the Win7 version of IExpress

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - it still has the same problem when built on Win7.

Comment: How can we reproduce the problem?

Comment: Can you check whether or not the executable is a 64 bit executable?

Comment: Create an .exe with iExpress in Windows 7, 64 bit then try to run it on Win 7, 32 bit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It sounds very much like you are creating a 64 bit executable, which cannot run on a 32 bit system. If you use the IExpress version from the 64 bit system directory, C:\Windows\System32, then you will indeed create a 64 bit executable.

You'll need to create a 32 bit executable instead, which you can do by running the 32 bit version of IExpress. That is found in the 32 bit system directory, C:\Windows\SysWOW64. Or you can use your 32 bit machine to create the executable.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it will give an error when running the exe in System32, Just send the EXE file to an empty folder and that will work.